# PHP Session Variable Will Not Unset

Tags: php, drupal, module, session-variables

I have a couple of lines of code in a Drupal module as so:

```
if ($arg == 'true' && isset($_SESSION['xyz']['noredirect'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['xyz']['noredirect']);
}
```

When the 2nd line is executed, I get error:

```
Error messageNotice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in blah() (line 122 of /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/blah/blah.module).
```

I simply cannot understand why if the session is set, I cannot unset it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: did u run session_start()

Comment: @Haim Drupal should handle session_start.

Comment: Thanks Haim, just so you know, I didn't write the module, I'm just trying to fix this one line as the rest of the module works fine. I cannot see session_start() in the module, should it be added somewhere? Thanks

Comment: @user What module hook are you using?

Comment: I'm seeing some comments about hook_menu(), hook_permission() and hook_init()

Answer (score 5):

It would appear that you are yet to run [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). This will create the `$_SESSION` superglobal.

Comment: It says "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()....   so it must have been in there somewhere. trickyzter suggested Drupal handles this?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($_SESSION)` ? If $_SESSION is NULL, then it hasn't been started and thus cannot have elements unset

Comment: The guy who wrote the module says it is working on the sites he has tested. He thinks its maybe an "environmental" problem with my site. Just don't know what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

The module now works exactly as I want it to. I solved it by using session_destroy(); rather than unset. It's probably not the most elegant way of fixing it but it works and I couldn't find any other way to do so.

```
if ($arg == 'true' && isset($_SESSION['xyz']['noredirect'])) {
session_destroy();
```

}